# Zip + 4 Centroids

Tags: latitude-longitude, centroids, zip-codes, zip4

I have a data set with ZIP +4 codes, and ideally, I'd like to map them (their centroids) as points. I'm not interested in their boundaries (since they're not really geographies anyway). Does anyone know of a resource that has point data for ZIP + 4s? Or might there be a better way to go about mapping this type of data?

Answer (score 5):

Nokia/NavTeq and TomTom both have datasets for sale/use that are Zip+4 points. These can be wildly inaccurate for many uses since a +4 record represents a Sector and Segment of a postal delivery route and can include several streets or miles of a single route.

Comment: Update 1: after a search of and call to TomTom, they say they shut down the maps division (formerly TeleAtlas).

Update 2: NavTeq is now called Here.

Answer (score 1):

Your easiest option to map ZIP+4 centroids would be to buy centroid files from [EASI](https://www.easidemographics.com), [Datasheer](https://www.zip-codes.com), [GreatData](https://greatdata.com), [Geolytics](https://www.geolytics.com), [Geocoder](https://geocoder.ca), or [AccuZip](https://www.accuzip.com).

You could also buy USPS ZIP+4 (non-geocoded) files and use GIS software or an API to geocode the address ranges.

The discussion in another post here might also be informative: [US ZIP Codes +4 By State or County- Shapefile (or table/dbf)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233982/us-zip-codes-4-by-state-or-county-shapefile-or-table-dbf)