# US ZIP Codes +4 By State or County- Shapefile (or table/dbf)

Tags: shapefile, latitude-longitude, zip-codes, postal-code, data-collection

I am looking for Zipcode data with the **+4 digits** at the end for a City (I can use it by state and clip the points to my municipal boundary), and with edges or geocodes. I called the post office and had no luck (national customer center in Memphis, TN- claimed that their +4 ZIP Code GIS Layer is not for the public).

Would anyone know where I could find this data?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56265/discussion-on-question-by-joe-us-zip-codes-4-by-state-or-county-shapefile-or).

Comment: Please don't use comments for your own personal conversations.  There is Chat available here, or many other non Stack Exchange ways to communicate.

Comment: Zipcodes are linear and/or point (PO Box) features, not polygons.

Comment: @Vince Who said anything about polygons?

Comment: Boundaries are clipped by polygons.

Comment: What? if they give me the entire state or County Zips(points) I only need them for my Municipality which I would clip those points(input) by that boundary(Clip feature).

Comment: Joe your question says "and clip my boundary" which makes it sound like you want to clip your boundary by your zip code data.  As @Vince says, boundaries are clipped by polygons.

Comment: Ah I guess that's what he meant, I apologize for my poor wording. I meant if they give me the entire state or County I can clip those points to my municipal boundary.

Comment: I am still Looking for this data

Comment: @Joe The USPS updates the AIS/AMS datasets every month; so you have a risk of having out of date data. For roughly $40.00 I believe you can subscribe to it from the USPS.

Comment: check out arcgisonline

Comment: ^^^ they only have the 5 digit Zip Codes

Answer (score 9):

Some background: The USPS maintains zip codes as sets of delivery zones(5 digit) and routes(+4 digits), usually along streets with address boundaries. USPS does not maintain zip codes in any shape format.

I had the issue of finding a viable source as well. I narrowed my possible solutions to the following 4 and chose to go with #3.

1. You can download the 5 digit data from https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html but the +4 data is not available from census or from the post office with +4 data.
2. Depending on how large your AOI is you can use the tool https://eddm.usps.com/eddm/customer/routeSearch.action to search zips. It will show the +4 routes which can be heads up digitized.
3. There are several companies that will sell you very accurate zip code data, Maponics being the one that I use. The five digit zip codes from them are pretty accurate. They do not offer zip+4 boundaries but they do have centroids for the +4 routes.
4. Your other option would be to request the address based data from USPS and attempt to create spatial data for it using parcels with addresses and streets as reference layers, though this would likely open a whole other can of worms.

Comment: 1. Wont work I need the +4 2. My AOI is entire City do not have the time to get every address zip+4. 3. Unfortunately this may be my only option. 4. This was my original plan when I contacted USPS, they have zip+4 GIS Layer but wont give it out its public information I don't see what the big deal is.

Comment: The interpretation of public information differs between government entities as well as between areas and levels of government. Some states/counties and entities have very lenient rules pertaining to what data can be released and the process for releasing it. Others place exceptions on certain types of data or require "processing fees" and security clearances for it to be released.

Comment: Update: Maponics was bought by Pitney Bowes, and then by Precisely. Some of the Maponics people are still at Precisely.

Comment: Correction (but useful only in niche cases): Census TIGER/Line ASCII files for 1992-2006 do have ZIP+4. From 2007-2021 ZIP+4 is no longer available in TIGER/Line Shapefiles. Of course, because ZIP+4 changes often the 1992-2006 ASCII files are more useful for geocoding historical data.

Comment: Update edit: Precisely won't license the ZIP+4 data, but do license to Datasheer (zip-codes.com) for sale.

Answer (score 2):

The plus 4 value is based on the address there is not a single number for a city.  It is not a universal number for a region as the first 5 digits are https://www.zip-codes.com/learn-about/what-is-a-zip-4-code.asp .  You will need to calculate it against some tiger data if you are trying to get every unique value and tie it to a region.

It would be relatively easy to scrape the values you want against this web services https://www.zip-codes.com/search.asp

Additionally, what you are asking for probably does not exist because it's not a requirement for delivery and was not universally accepted... not all address have a +4: Source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_Code#ZIP.2B4

Comment: FYI, the first 5 digits are not a universal number for a region. That's why [ZCTAs](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/zctas.html) were created.

Comment: Yeah universal might not be the right word. the first 5 covers an area the last 4 is for a point.

Comment: the GIS Layer does exist which is why I am asking for it here. USPS has it but they claim its not for the public.... but the information itself is public information nothing "classified" hoping someone knew of another source.

Comment: Maybe you should try asking this on opendata stack. Your asking for a data source not a "GIS how to" might have better luck there.

Answer (score 1):

The `ZipPlus4` information seems to be available in the (old) Tiger/Line 2000 data. e.g. ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/tgrcd108/FL/tgr12099.zip for Palm Beach County, FL.

According to [gdal driver documentation](http://www.gdal.org/drv_tiger.html),

> Feature Representation  Following is a list of feature types, and
>   their relationship to the TIGER/Line product.
>
> CompleteChain
>
> A CompleteChain is a polyline with an associated TLID (TIGER/Line ID).
>   The CompleteChain features are established from a type 1 record
>   (Complete Chain Basic Data Record), and if available it's associated
>   type 3 record (Complete Chain Geographic Entity Codes). As well, any
>   type 2 records (Complete Chain Shape Coordinates) available are used
>   to fill in intermediate shape points on the arc.
>
> ...
>
> **ZipPlus4**
>
> These features are derived from type Z (ZIP+4 Codes) records.
>   ZipPlus4 features have a many to one relationship with CompleteChain
>   features.

However, the linked Tiger/Line 2000 data is in report type (.RT) files format, not in current GIS format.

Here are some example output for running `ogrinfo TGR12099.RT1 ZipPlus4`:

```
OGRFeature(ZipPlus4):50424
  MODULE (String) = TGR12099
  TLID (Integer) = 115356454
  RTSQ (Integer) = 0
  ZIP4L (Integer) = 3366
  ZIP4R (Integer) = 3367

OGRFeature(ZipPlus4):50425
  MODULE (String) = TGR12099
  TLID (Integer) = 115356457
  RTSQ (Integer) = 0
  ZIP4L (Integer) = 6048
  ZIP4R (Integer) = 6049

OGRFeature(ZipPlus4):50426
  MODULE (String) = TGR12099
  TLID (Integer) = 115356460
  RTSQ (Integer) = 0
  ZIP4L (Integer) = 2680
  ZIP4R (Integer) = 5151

OGRFeature(ZipPlus4):50427
  MODULE (String) = TGR12099
  TLID (Integer) = 115356485
  RTSQ (Integer) = 0
  ZIP4L (Integer) = 0
  ZIP4R (Integer) = 0
```

(Note: the `TLID` represents "complete chains" or arcs in the network). The complete chains are topologically correct according to the [meta data](https://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/maps-data/data/tiger/tgrcd108/tl108meta.txt):

> - Complete chains must begin and end at nodes.
> - Complete chains must connect to each other at nodes.
> - Complete chains do not extend through nodes.
> - Left and right GT-polygons are defined for each complete chain  element and are consistent throughout the extract process.

There is an GIS.SE question 
([Anyone who has the ESRI Census 2000 Tiger/Line data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92090/anyone-who-has-the-esri-census-2000-tiger-line-data)), which has an answer describing a script for converting the .RT files to shapefiles. I haven't tested it myself, but the code may be relevant.

Also, USPS really defines the ZIP(+4) codes etc. and may change it over time, so the Tiger/Line 2000 from census data may be outdated. Also, I am not an expert with Tiger data. You might want to check with the US Census/Tiger-line people to see if the ZipPlus4 is available in the current tiger-line files in GIS format.

Comment: This data is far too old for me to use

Comment: @Joe, as I said `You might want to check with the US Census/Tiger-line people to see if the ZipPlus4 is available in the current tiger-line files in GIS format.` Historically, it's there in older formats.

Comment: ZIP+4 was only available in TIGER/Line from 1994-2006, and according to Census staff will not be coming back in public releases. Also, ZIP+4 changes often due to reassignment of postal routes, so any more than a year away from a given snapshot and the trail starts to go cold.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Census hasn't included ZIP+4 values in TIGER/Line Shapefiles since 2006, and the data provider Maponics suggested by @Kingfisher folded into Pitney Bowes / Precisely and does not license their data directly (edit: they do license to Datasheer, see below).

That leaves three options:

1. Centroid files from [EASI](https://www.easidemographics.com), [Datasheer](https://www.zip-codes.com), [GreatData](https://greatdata.com), [Geolytics](https://www.geolytics.com), [Geocoder](https://geocoder.ca), or [AccuZip](https://www.accuzip.com).
2. APIs from [SmartyStreets](https://www.smartystreets.com) or [Geocodio](https://www.geocod.io).
3. USPS ZIP+4 (non-geocoded) product: you can run its address ranges through a geocoding API or GIS software. If you wanted to do this for historic ZIP+4, you could buy older snapshots ($825 national, $52.50 for one state, available back to 1994) and use the current City-State street name alias file to deal with street name changes.

- This suggestion comes from the USPS Addressing and Geospatial Technology Group.
- After talking with USPS and Census, I agree with the suggestion by @Kingfisher not to merge ZIP+4 onto Census TIGER/Line address ranges (edges).

Answer (score -1):

A common misconception is that zip codes are areas, when in fact they are routes.
You can conceptualize the area these routes occupy and make your analysis that way, but many people will see this as a flawed or problematic analysis especially if your data type conflicts with or exaggerates error created by that flawed understanding of zip codes.

Comment: That is a valid comment; but doesn't help address the question posed since he didn't provide a good use-case for needing the values.